# make fail on nextgenmap-lr : /usr/bin/ld: attempted static link of dynamic object `/usr/local/lib/libz.so'

Tags: gcc, dynamic, g++, installation

my error message is

```
[ 96%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/ngmlr.dir/unix.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/ngmlr.dir/unix_threads.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/ngmlr-0.1.6/ngmlr
/usr/bin/ld: attempted static link of dynamic object`/usr/local/lib/libz.so'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../bin/ngmlr-0.1.6/ngmlr] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/ngmlr.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/libz.so*
 libz.so -> libz.so.1.2.8
 libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.8
 libz.so.1.2.8
```

Link path of my ZLIB
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/local/lib/libz.so (found version "1.2.8")

my system is ubuntu 14.10

I have reinstalled the zlib-1.2.8, But I had the same questions
How can I find a solution to this problem
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by either adding the static libraries to your system (e.g. yum install zlib-static) or editing the CMakeLists.txt file to disable the static compile (ie set the == option(STATIC "Build static binary" OFF))